# Yii2 get user ip address in every http request

Tags: php, yii2

Am creating a restful api in yii2 and am looking forward to get the logs of all application access capturing the ip addresses used to access the application

In my controller i have added this

```
public function actionLogin(){
  //fetch request ip here then save to log
 }

public function actionRequestResetPassword(){
  //fetch request ip here then save to log
 }
```

As from the above there is alot of code duplication. Is it possible to create a high order action that does so in every request

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html

Comment: @AlivetoDie How does this help?

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI AliveToDie's link shows you a method by which you can obtain the IP address.

Comment: Actually you have two link:- https://prnt.sc/giplza

Comment: Getting the ip address is not the issue here but the issue is alot of code duplication in every controller action. I thought maybe there is something that exists that can log all application access